# Problems Creating a Subset in R

Tags: r

I'm an R newbie and need some help analyzing data about incarcerated individuals for a project. The data set I'm working with includes information from a jail spanning the months October 2015 to July 2016. I want to do quick summary statistics broken down by month. I tried to create an October subset first using this formula:

```
myworkOCTOBER <- subset(mywork, BEGINDATE=="2015-10-01" & ENDDATE=="2015-10-31")
```

But when I try to pull the summary statistics using this formula:

`summary(myworkOCTOBER)`

...the output just doesn't seem right.

Please advise!!!

Comment: "output just doesn't seem right" is pretty vague. Could you be more specific on what you're seeing? (It also helps if you can include a sample of the data you're working with to reproduce the problem)

Comment: The big question here is whether your dates are coded as actual `Date` class objects or if they are strings or factors. You are treating them like they are not `Date`s, but it will be easier if they are.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this without availability of the data, but you could try using the `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mywork %>%
    mutate(month = month(BEGINDATE)) %>%
    group_by(month) %>%
    summarize(example_of_stat_mean = mean(VARIABLENAME),
              example_of_stat_sd = sd(VARIABLENAME))
```

This is just an example (you would need to change `VARIABLENAME` and the function (i.e., `mean`, `sd`) based on which statistic you want to calculate for which variable(s).